# Pivot table hyperlinks

Tags: excel, pivot

Is there a way to create a pivot table and include text with clickable hyperlinks? something like this:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: I doubt it. That looks like a regular table though, which can easily include hyperlinks.

Comment: It is. Just wanted to give an example of what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen a solution that interprets a link in a pivot table. So, not the most beautiful way but you could add a column afterwards your pivot table with =HYPERLINK([Cell with Link]) and format this column like you need it. Like so: "link" is your "registration link" column
[image: sample]